# trying to get ajax response from javascript using OOP object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

so this is my code :

```
 function CreateDiv(D) {

   D.body = function () {

            var d =
                 $.ajax({
                     type: "GET",
                     url: "Default.aspx",
                     data: 'ExtrFlag=GetChat&userID=1&FriendID=' + this.id,
                     success: function (data) {
                         var StrResponse;
                         StrResponse = data.split('@@@');
                         return StrResponse[0];
                     },
                     error: function (xhr) {
                         return xhr.responseText;
                     }
                 });
            alert(d);

            return "<div class='chatBody' id='chatBody" + this.id + "' >" + d + "</div>";
     };

 }
 function NewChat(id,username,picture) {

        var div = new CreateDiv({ width: 250, height: 285, id: id, username: username, picture: picture });
        div.create();
    }
```

the problem is when the ajax call is executed the result is `d=[object object]` but in my case it should be a string because the ajax server side function always returns a string.

Comment: `console.log()`, not `alert()`.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is not the return value of the ajax request but the actual ajax request handler itself. the value that is returned from the server is `data` in your case.

Since ajax is by definition asynchronous you cant use it the way you are using it in a function. You should handle all the required proccessing in the success handler or you can return a handle on the ajax request itself and use [$.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [$.promise()](http://api.jquery.com/promise/) to handle the processing elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can't return a value from an asynchronous method, all the code that deals with the response of the ajax request should be added to the success/failure handlers of the ajax request.